# Question about training a object detecting model but the images of train dataset have many miss-annotation objects

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

- in the train dataset, some objects that should to be labeled but didn't cause some reasons.
- like the picture below, some objects missed annotation(red rectangle is the labeled one).
- [image with miss-annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8LKB.png)
- what should i do to the uncomplete labeled dataset and what's the effect to the model(maybe overfit to the test data cause false negetive when training)?

Answer (score 6):

Most detection algorithms use portion of images without bounding boxes as examples of "negative" images, meaning images that should not be detected.
If you have many objects in your training set which should have been labeled but aren't, this is a problem because it confuses the training algorithm.

You should definitely think about manually adding the missing labels to the dataset.